# erorr AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Tags: python, error-reporting

my code is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class instagrambot:
    def __init__(self, username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='F:\\PUNEET\\python\\SETUP\\geckodriver-v0.28.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe')

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
        time.sleep(5)
        bot.find_elements_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)

insta = instagrambot('username','password')
insta.login()
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

what could I do?
I also change from name to xpath but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sendkeys works on an individual element. What you have is a list of elements (not sure why you wanted a list?) Usually there is only one username field in a login page. Use FindElement (note NOT FindElementS) instead to find the element to send keys to.